# Enemy is destroyed without actually hitting the trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 2D Sidescroller in Unity right now and have some problems regarding the enemy.

In theory I want the enemy be destroyed if the player jumps on it's head(upper collider/trigger) and the player loses health if he hits the other collider/trigger.

Well the player loses health when hitting the enemy from the side but it also destroys the enemy and I don't know why.
It isn't even near the deathCollider.

Upper collider tag(isTrigger) : enemyHit

(this one is placed at the top of the enemy)

Bigger center collider tag(isTrigger) : enemy

(this one is under the other collider and encloses the rest of the body)

Sorry can't post an image :/

My onTrigger method in the playerScript looks like this

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
    if (other.tag == "spike") {
        GotHit();
    }
    if (other.tag == "groundTrap") {
        InstandDeath();
    }
    if (other.tag == "enemy") {
        //hitEnemy = other.gameObject;
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(hitSound, transform.position, 10.0f);
        GotHit();
    }
    if (other.tag == "enemyHit") {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        rigidbody2D.AddForce (jumpVector, ForceMode2D.Force);
        //switch animation to 'jump'
        anim.SetInteger("AnimationStatePink", 2);
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(jumpSound, transform.position, 10.0f);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

And the enemyScript only has it's movement

```
    public float enemySpeed;
private Vector3 movement;
public static bool startEnemyMovement = true;
//set walking limits
public float leftLimit, rightLimit;
//adjust scaling
public float scaleX, scaleY;
public float rotateX, rotateY;

public void Start(){
    movement = Vector3.left * enemySpeed;
}

public void Update() {

    if (startEnemyMovement == true)
        EnemyMovement ();

    if (PinkPlayerControler.isPaused == true)
        startEnemyMovement = false;
    else
        startEnemyMovement = true;
}

void EnemyMovement(){
    if (this.transform.position.x > rightLimit) {
        movement = Vector3.left * enemySpeed;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(-scaleX,scaleY,1);
    } else if (this.transform.position.x < leftLimit) {
        movement = Vector3.right * enemySpeed;
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX,scaleY,1);
    }
    transform.Translate(movement);
}
```

Edit:

the GotHit() method looks like this

```
    void GotHit (){
    if(Health.gameLives > 1){
        Health.gameLives--;
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(hitSound, transform.position, 10.0f);
    }
    else {
        youLose();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Chrizzly

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` statements inside of each of your tag-checking `if` blocks to see which triggers are being activated and when. Are you certain the player isn't touching the `enemyHit` trigger?

Comment: I tried it and now I'm more confused. It just triggers the playerHit method and the other one at no time.

Comment: If that's the case, then clearly something weird is happening in `GotHit`. Can you show us that function?

Comment: I edited my original post. Oh and thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: Well clearly that's not doing anything terrible so I'm not sure what's going on. It could be something else going on somewhere in another script. But I'm pretty sure the code you've showed here is not to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason...you were right - I have a script that gives the player point for defeating an enemy and there was still some test code that destroyed the complete GameObject -.- Thanks for the help :) –